# Handling Python Requests JSON Response

Tags: python, arrays, json, unicode, python-requests

Trying to handle some JSON response to a Python Requests call to an API, in Python--a language I'm still learning.

Here's the structure of the sample returned JSON data:

```
{"sports":[{"searchtype":"seasonal", "sports":["'baseball','football','softball','soccer','summer','warm'","'hockey','curling','luge','snowshoe','winter','cold'"]}]}
```

Currently, I'm parsing and writing output to a file like this:

```
output = response.json
results = output['sports'][0]['sports']
     if results:
          with open (filename, "w") as fileout:
               fileout.write(pprint.pformat(results))
```

Giving me this as my file:

```
[u"'baseball','football','softball','soccer','summer','warm'",
"'hockey','curling','luge','snowshoe','winter','cold'"]
```

Since I'm basically creating double-quoted JSON Arrays, consisting of comma separated strings--how can I manipulate the array to print only the comma separated values I want?  In this case, everything except the fifth column which represents seasons.

```
[u"'baseball','football','softball','soccer','warm'",
"'hockey','curling','luge','snowshoe','cold'"]
```

Ultimately, I'd like to strip away the unicode too, since I have no non-ascii characters.  I currently do this manually with a language I'm more familiar with (AWK) after the fact.  My desired output is really:

```
'baseball','football','softball','soccer','warm'
'hockey','curling','luge','snowshoe','cold'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your results is actually a list of strings, to get your desired output you can do it like this for example:

```
 if results:
      with open (filename, "w") as fileout:
          for line in results
              fileout.write(line)
```

Comment: Yep.  You were absolutely correct.  Works much better this way.